# Asymptotic Notation for factorial functions

Tags: asymptotics

Indicate whether or not each function below is $( \log ())$:

1) $\dfrac{5^2}{\log(n)^3}$

2)$\log((^2)!)$

I am stuck when I try to simplify these functions and find their growth rates.

Comment: use stirling...

Comment: What is giving you trouble in part 1?

Comment: showing that its simplified form implies ( log )

Comment: I can't see any way to simplify `1)`, what if you use it as it is?